# JS confirm() cancel button still submits form

Tags: javascript, .net

I've created a confirmation box that does submit the form when "Ok" is clicked, however the form still submits when "Cancel" is clicked as well and I'd like that to stop, any help would be very much appreciated. See code below, and please let me know what else you may need from me, I'd be happy to post it.

```
function confirmation() {
    var r = confirm("Would you like to make a deposit?");
    if (r == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnApplyPayment" runat="server" TabIndex="750" Text="Apply &gt;&gt;"ValidationGroup ="vgPayment" OnClientClick ="confirmation();" />
```

Comment: missed one minor thing.... `OnClientClick ="return confirmation();"`

Comment: thanks for the reply! This worked, but it no longer submits when I click Ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe catch the submit event like this.

```html
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Would you like to make a deposit?')">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```